# Forms Authentication & IIS7 (&MVC): Why ReturnUrl=/ is added?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis-7, forms-authentication

When trying to access my site:

www.X.com

The browser changes the url to:

www.X.com/

The problem is that the result url is:

www.X.com/HomePage.aspx?ReturnUrl=/

(HomePage.aspx is the default page)

On IE: www.X.com/HomePage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

For some reason the Forms Authentication treats / as a page that the user is trying to access and then gets redirects to: HomePage.aspx?ReturnUrl=/

How can I set the Forms Authentication (or the MVC routing) not to treat / as a page, so when accessing www.X.com it will not change the url?

The site runs on windows server 2008 IIS7, .NET 4.

(When running on IIS6 it didn't have this problem)

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".AUTHCOOKIE" loginUrl="HomePage.aspx" defaultUrl="Loading.aspx" timeout="9480" />
  </authentication>
```

MVC Routing (not sure it’s related):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ascx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Actions", "A/{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Tasks", action = "InitPage" });

    }
```

Thanks

Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you access http://www.x.com, you are requesting http://www.x.com/. When you get redirected to the validation form in IIS/.Net, RedirectTo= is always appended at the end of the URL, so that the server knows where do you wanted to go before your request was intercepted.

Or to put it another way: everything is working as expected. What's exactly what you want to do?

If it helps, I see two things "weird" with the code you included:

- The Login page is called HomePage.aspx. That's... unusual (with that name, HomePage.aspx should be the page you go to after login, not the login page). Moreover, you mention MVC, but that's not a MVC route.
- Your only route in Global.asax starts with "A/", so that http://www.x.com/ won't be captured by it. If your start page must be http://www.x.com/A/Tasks/InitPage, either make A a route parameter {whatever}, and assign it a default value, or create another MapRoute that captures the "/" request, and redirects to the correct path. Probably adding a Default.aspx to the project would work, but it would be very un-MVC.

Comment: Here’s what I want: When accessing www.X.com access Homepage.aspx but without any URL change (Not even www.X.com/HomePage.aspx - it worked on IIS 6). Instead on IIS7 it redirects to www.X.com/HomePage.aspx?ReturnUrl=/ . It’s something to do with Forms Authentication & IIS7 I’m not sure what I need to change.

Comment: Aaah! Then it's easy (I think). It's just that Homepage.aspx is not configured to be the default page returned by http://www.X.com (in IIS, you have just default.aspx, index.html, and a few variations). Because of that, "http://www.X.com/" != "http://www.X.com/HomePage.aspx", and you get the RedirectTo parameter appended.

Comment: Homepage.aspx is set as the default page (thats why it worked on IIS6)

Comment: For some reason IIS/Asp.net is not able to realize that "/" = "/Hompage.aspx" (the only time when the server doesn't redirect you to the full login URL + RedirectTo is when the URL is that of the login form). I can't tell you much more than that, however. If it helps, a solution for your problem might be making your homepage.aspx public, that way it wouldn't be IIS who redirects you to it, and the URL wouldn't change.

Comment: In this URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx you'll find an example of how to grant anonymous access to a specific file (Logon.aspx in the example, HomePage.aspx in yours). You just have to add an <allow> tag in your web.config, inside a <location> tag to specify that it only affects one page and not the whole site.

Answer (score 3):

First step:
You can set Web config files as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".AUTHCOOKIE" loginUrl="/" defaultUrl="Loading.aspx" timeout="9480" />
</authentication>
```

Step 2:
Will your web server's (IIS) default document Settings for "Loading. aspx"

Comment: This fixed it for me on IIS 7.5, the other suggestions on this page did nothing to correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add to global asax. I had a similar problem and this seemed to fix it.

```
Private Sub Global_asax_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest
    If (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.ToLower = "~/".ToLower) Then
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Index.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

> ALSO make sure path="/" is not present in your authentication code
>   block

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Index.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>
```

*note. You can convert vb.net to c# here http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

Add access permission to your Login page, for example:

```
 <location path="Login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

and the form tag is:

```
<forms name="SecurityAuthentication" path="/"  loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="60" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in `login.aspx.cs` put the following statement:

```
if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null && Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != "/")
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
```

The most important part is this condition:

```
Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != "/"
```

Comment: If we debug into the code, `ReturnUrl=%2f` actually means `ReturnUrl=/`. It had a hard time redirecting to "/"; so we just ignore. It works. For any other `ReturnUrl`, we redirect to that url by doing `Response.Redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to switch my AppPool "Managed Pipeline Mode" back from "Integrated" to "Classic".